# how to solve problem involving a condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematica-online

I am new to mathematica, therefore this might be a pretty simple question,
My problem is for example: Compute the eigenvalue for matrix A= {{1,c},{1/c,1}}, c>0.
when the matrix becomes more complicated, the "Eigenvalues[A]" command usually gives me something like "root[...]", therefore I want to assign variable "c" with a condition. How do I do this?

Comment: *usually gives me something like "root[...]"* What are you expecting to get? Do you understand that polynomials of order 5 and higher don’t necessarily have roots that are expressible in terms of radicals?

Comment: instead of using only words to describe things, it is always better to also give an actual small example that shows the problem you are having. There are few questions in this forum asking about how to handle and remove Root in results given by Mathematica. May be you can check these.

Comment: yeah sorry should be A= {{1,c},{1/c,1}},

Comment: was just trying to give an simple example, I know result like "root[...]" is normal. 
I just want to know how to assign a condition to a variable in a matrix in general

Comment: To make assumptions you could look at [Assumptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) for examples. You can also use [Assuming](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html)

Comment: for example the code Im working on right now 
`a = {{1, 1, c}, {1, 1, 1}, {1/c, 1, 1}}
c > 0
MatrixForm[a]
Eigenvalues[a]
Eigenvectors[a]`
I want the matrix to have positive entries. but c>0 here doesnt seem to work

Comment: be careful using `MatrixForm[a]` as you can use this any more in computation. `MatrixForm` is a wrapper. Always use   `(a=.....) // MatrixForm` this prevents MatrixFrom from sticking to  your matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert root to radicals using ToRadicals. Just use Eigenvalues then apply ToRadicals then simplify using $c>0$.

```
 (a = {{1, 1, c}, {1, 1, 1}, {1/c, 1, 1}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eig=Eigenvalues[a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eig=ToRadicals[eig]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Assuming[c>0,Simplify[eig]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You do do all the above also using

```
(a={{1,1,c},{1,1,1},{1/c,1,1}})//MatrixForm
char=CharacteristicPolynomial[a,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eig = Solve[char == 0, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Assuming[c > 0, Simplify[eig]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you so much, this answered my question.
and for telling me to use MatrixForm[a] carefully